# Evaluate a Macro Argument Before Processing

Tags: c++, macros, arguments, conditional-statements, precompile

I want to be able to generate these options from a macro:

1. `if(void* temp = func(arg)){ foo(temp, variable);return; }`
2. `if(void* temp = func2(arg)){ foo(temp, variable2);return; }`
3. `if(void* temp = func3(arg)){ foo(temp, variable3);return; }`

And so on, but as you can see **1** is the only special case.

I want to write a macro which takes in a number as a parameter and generates a line this code, potentially with numbers far greater than 3. Unfortunately this requires building in the special case if the user passed a 1 and exercising the general case if they passed any other number. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Instead of macro hell, why not populate an array of function pointers?  Then you can just index into the array in the if statement using the supplied index (with nothing in the zeroith index.)

Comment: @NathanOliver There are definitely better ways to do this, primarily starting with things like using arrays, or some other association between `func` and `variable`, but because I do not own the code here, I thought that a macro might be easier, and wouldn't require me to define my own mapping array, out of which I will likely only use 1 mapping.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the CPP for this, it's easy enough.  An indirect `GLUE` and an indirect `SECOND` macro are core tools that you could use:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(_,X,...) X
```

The indirect `SECOND` allows you to *pattern match* in the preprocessor.  The way that works is that you build a first token, which is normally just a throwaway.  But since expansion is indirect, if that first token you build is a macro, it will expand first (namely, as part of argument substitution for the variadic).  If that expansion contains a comma, it can shift in a "new" second argument right before the indirection picks the second one.  You can use that to build your special cases.

Here's a cpp pattern matcher using this construct that returns its argument unless it is 1, in which case it expands to no tokens:

```
#define NOT_ONE(N) SECOND(GLUE(TEST_IF_1_IS_,N),N)
#define TEST_IF_1_IS_1 ,
```

Using that, your macro might be:

```
#define DISPATCH_CASE(N) \
   if(void* temp = GLUE(func,NOT_ONE(N))){ \
      foo(temp, GLUE(variable,NOT_ONE(N))); \
      return;
   }
```

[Demo (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a834bc96c79400e)

**Update: Visual Studio version**

> But I'm on Visual Studio, and I can't make it work.   I think the problem is the __VA_ARGS__ expansion works differently on Visual Studio

For VS, I've found another level of indirection of a particular sort (one that separates the macro from its arguments so the arg list can evaluate in a simple `(...)` context before it's applied) helps it figure out that commas delimit arguments.  Typically I would repeat the same pattern in multiple macros to avoid blue paint.

Here, that translates to the slightly uglier:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_C(GLUE_I,(A,B))
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define GLUE_C(A,B) A B
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_C(SECOND_I,(__VA_ARGS__,,))
#define SECOND_I(_,X,...) X
#define SECOND_C(A,B) A B
```

[Demo (goldbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/bZHWcL)